# What is this chart's image?

Tags: general-topology

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uinS3.png)

Can someoen elaborate the statement

"$v_z$  maps the interval $I_c$ to a neighborhood of $z$ given by $S^1 - \{ -z \}$"

So I pick $c = 0$ and $z = (1,0)$, then it maps $I_0 \to$ the open set containing $z = (1,0)$, that is $N_z = (1 \pm 1/2,\pm 1/2)$. Why is the reflection point $-z$ omitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $J$ is an open real interval of length $1$ or less, the restriction $f|_J $ of the function $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$ to the domain $J$ is a homeomorphism to an open  subspace of $S^1.$

If the length of $J$ is greater than $1,$ or if the length of $J$ is $1$ and $J$ contains one or both of its endpoints, then $f|_J$ is not a homeomorphism of $J$ to its image.

They have chosen $f,$ and  open intervals of length $1,$ to get the largest possible homeomorphic images, that is, $S^1$ minus one point. You can always rotate the circle $S^1$ so that the omitted point is any one you want.

You can't  homeomorphically map a subspace of $\mathbb R$ onto all of $S^1.$

Comment: I never noticed the interval is at most length 1.